# $\cos x = 12/13$ ,where $0<x<90^\circ$ , find the value of $\sin(2x)$ .

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $\cos x = 12/13$, where $0<x<90^\circ$, find the value of $\sin(2x)$.

I can't do this question, can you teach me?

Comment: When you have trouble remembering trigonometric formula's try drawing a complete triangle and then taking your required things from the triangle .

Answer (score 8):

If $\cos x=\frac{12}{13}$ and $x$ is an acute angle, $\sin x=\frac{5}{13}$, since $(5,12,13)$ is a well-known Pythagorean triple, and
$$ \sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \frac{120}{169}$$
by the sine duplication formula.

Answer (score 3):

use the two trigonometric identities
$$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$$
$$ \sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints: 1) Can you find $\sin x$?
2) Once you know $\sin x$, do you know the expansion formula for $\sin 2x$ in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a right angled triangle. Note that using Pythagoras thm

the Adjacent side= 12, Opposite side= 5, Hypotenuse =13.

$$ \sin 2 (..) = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 12 /13^2 =120/169 $$

Comment: You meant to write $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 12$ rather than $2512$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle with adjacent side $12$ and hypotenuse $13$ (see *figure 1*). This triangle will have an angle ($x$, or alternatively $\angle BAC$) with a cosine of $\frac{12}{13}. $Try to find side $\overline{BC}$ to make the calculation of the other trigonometric ratios easier (especially $\sin x$ <== hint hint). The Pythagorean Theorem works well here.

Next, draw a duplicate triangle underneath it (see *figure 1* again) and use the law of sines to show that
$$\frac{\sin 2x}{BD} = \frac{\sin\measuredangle B}{AD}$$.

**Hint:** Do you see why $\sin \measuredangle B = \cos x$?

Can you generalize the preceding to derive the following identity?
$$\sin 2x = 2\sin x\cos x$$

**Figure 1**

[image: Figure 1]